# SQL Query for Time in , Time out Report

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the below sample output.

**personnel_employee**

| emp_code | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name 1 | last 1 |
| 4 | name 4 | last 4 |
| 7 | name 7 | last 7 |

**iclock_transaction**

| emp_code | punch_time |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 29/03/2023 19:55:57 |
| 4 | 29/03/2023 18:38:23 |
| 1 | 29/03/2023 17:30:10 |
| 7 | 29/03/2023 08:46:12 |
| 4 | 29/03/2023 08:32:21 |
| 1 | 29/03/2023 12:12:01 |
| 1 | 29/03/2023 08:12:01 |

I want to build a query to achieve the below results:

| emp_code | first_name | last_name | date | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name 1 | last 1 | 29/03/2023 | 08:12:01 | 17:30:10 |
| 4 | name 4 | last 4 | 29/03/2023 | 08:32:21 | 18:38:23 |
| 7 | name 7 | last 7 | 29/03/2023 | 08:46:12 | 19:55:57 |

Comment: Why the row for employee 1 and punch_time 29/03/2023 12:12:01 is ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You can try do something like this. But make sure to have relevant indexes to run this query efficiently.

```sql
SELECT 
    p.emp_code, 
    p.first_name, 
    p.last_name, 
    DATE(t.punch_time) AS date,
    MIN(TIME(t.punch_time)) AS time_in, 
    MAX(TIME(t.punch_time)) AS time_out 
FROM personnel_employee p 
JOIN iclock_transaction t 
    ON p.emp_code = t.emp_code 
GROUP BY 
    p.emp_code, 
    p.first_name, 
    p.last_name, 
    DATE(t.punch_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Related, and too long for a Comment.)

I recommend using `TIMESTAMP` not `DATE` + `TIME`.  This simplifies computations and avoids issues with DST (Daylight Stupid Time).  It is simple enough to do `TIME(...)` in the `SELECT`. and use `DATE_FORMAT` to rearrange the date as desired.